# What is the correct way to write a Date in JavaScript without having browsers do any adjustments related to timezone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I'm not in the GMT timezone and `new Date('1995-02-22')` gives me

```
new Date('1995-02-22') <-- Enter this in the console


Tue Feb 21 1995 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

I'm coding something related to a birthday, so the year month and day are super important, but the time isn't. What is the proper way to handle this? Using moment.js seems beyond overkill.

Comment: Dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, so they do not have a timezone. Your issue is that *Date.prototype.toString* uses host system settings to produce a timestamp in the "local" timezone. If you want YYYY-MM-DD parsed as local, then do it yourself: `let [y, m, d] = '1995-02-22'.split(/\D/); let date = new Date(y, m-1, d)`.

Answer (score 0):

Choose one: either create a Date with the correct date in UTC time, or with the correct date in the local timezone. If the timestamp might be used by other clients too, use UTC time for easy compatibility.

If you create the Date with the correct UTC time, then just use the get* UTC methods to retrieve the year/month/day.

```js
const date = new Date('1995-02-22');
console.log(
  date.getUTCFullYear(),
  (date.getUTCMonth() + 1), // 0 indexed
  date.getUTCDate(),
);
```

Or create the Date in local time and use the local versions of the above, like `.getFullYear`.

Comment: The problem I have is I have a server giving say '1995-02-22' and I have a vue component taking a Date. So when I create the date It says 1995-02-21 instead of 22

Comment: What do you mean by "it says"? If you use the appropriate methods to extract the UTC numbers from the date, you'll get the correct UTC numbers.

Comment: Yes but the vue component takes a Date() not separate numbers that I could get by extracting UTC numbers

Comment: So I need to pass a Date() object that says 22, I think the only solution is to add the timezone offset but this is annoying

Comment: Sounds like you need to either refactor the component so that it takes UTC values from the date (which is what I'd prefer by far, I'd rather not deal with local time issues), or change the time string passed to include the timezone

Comment: Yeah this is from an external library so refactoring it isnt an option. For changing the string, like this `new Date('1995-02-22T00:00:00.000Z')` chrome still shows Feb 21 and so does the component, so given that I'm -8 (PST) I can get it to work by forcing +8 but this is kinda ridiculous

Comment: If the component uses the local methods under the hood, and you're not able to change the component, then your only option is to pass in a time that factors in the local offset

Comment: `dob.value = new Date(d.dob)
          dob.value.setMinutes(dob.value.getUTCMinutes() + dob.value.getTimezoneOffset())`

This fixed it (adjusting to the timezone offset)